# Retrieving metadata from xml files

Tags: c#, .net, xml, metadata

I need to retrieve metadata from multiple xml files. The structure of the xml file is the following:

```
<songs>
 <song_title> some title </song_title>
 <classification> some classification </classification>
 <song_text> some text </song_text>
 <singer>
    <sing> singer's name </sing>
    <gender> gender </gender>
    <bornYear> year </bornYear>
    <livePlace> live place </livePlace>
    <liveArea> live area </liveArea>
  </singer>
</songs>
```

The user chooses the search criteria - live place or live area. Then he enters the name of the place or area, that he searches for. I need to find and display links to songs, which have in its metadata the place or area, that user has entered. I am using .NET 3.5

Answer (score 1):

This answer is more of a pointer...

You can use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx) to accomplish this task.

**What Is LINQ to XML?**

> LINQ to XML is a LINQ-enabled,
>   in-memory XML programming interface
>   that enables you to work with XML from
>   within the .NET Framework programming
>   languages.
>
> LINQ to XML is like the Document
>   Object Model (DOM) in that it brings
>   the XML document into memory. You can
>   query and modify the document, and
>   after you modify it you can save it to
>   a file or serialize it and send it
>   over the Internet. However, LINQ to
>   XML differs from DOM: It provides a
>   new object model that is lighter
>   weight and easier to work with, and
>   that takes advantage of language
>   improvements in Visual C# 2008.

You can then search and manipulate any XML document element using LINQ query expressions like the following example:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> partNos =
from item in purchaseOrder.Descendants("Item")
where (int) item.Element("Quantity") *
    (decimal) item.Element("USPrice") > 100
orderby (string)item.Element("PartNumber")
select item;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPathing to easily get whatever you want if you have an aversion to Linq

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086%28VS.85%29.aspx

```
node.SelectNodes("Songs[/Singer/LivePlace='California']")
```

this would get all Songs nodes that have a singer node with a liveplace node with the value of California.